# pinia in hooks can't update the state's value

Tags: typescript, frontend, vuejs3, pinia

**→ src/hooks/useLogin.ts**

```
loginApi(param)
      .then((res: any) => {
        const { accountId, token, name } = res.result
        const userPinia = useUserPinia(pinia)
        userPinia.setUserBaseInfo({ accountId, token, name })
        ElMessage.success('login success')
        router.push(route.path)
      })
```

**→ src/pinia/user.ts**

```
export { default as pinia } from './pinia'
export { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import store from 'store-js'

export const useUserPinia = defineStore('userPinia', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      userBaseInfo: null,
    } as UseUserPinia
  },
  getters: {
    getUserBaseInfo(state) {
      if (!state.userBaseInfo) {
        const userBaseInfo = store.get('userBaseInfo')
        if (userBaseInfo) state.userBaseInfo = userBaseInfo
      }
      return state.userBaseInfo
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setUserBaseInfo(data?: UserBaseInfo) {
      console.log('%c here setUserBaseInfo','color:orange;')
      this.userBaseInfo = data || null
      if(data) store.set('userBaseInfo', data)
      else store.remove('userBaseInfo')
    },
  },
})
```

and next I got the message in console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9kZu.png)

but, the user info didn't show on the view,
and, check it in vue-devtools, the data is null:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KUIq.png)

why the user info is already existed and already triggered the 'pinia action function', but it doesn't updated?

**→ UserInfo.vue**

```
const userPinia = useUserPinia()
const { userBaseInfo } = storeToRefs(userPinia)
```

It doesn't work.

I want to update the data in pinia, in a .ts file

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem occurs in this file: main.ts

I have import an useAppInit function in main.ts:

```
import …
import useAppInit from './hooks/useAppInit'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(createPinia())
app.mount('#app')
useAppInit()
```

And in './hooks/useAppInit' I have used pinia already.
I find the illustrate in pinia's official website: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html
Here explianed that I should'nt call 'useXxxStore()' before the pinia is created